# wp admin user name has been changed by someone

Tags: wordpress

As a Administrator of my website (Wordpress with Woocommerce), I am unable to logged in on my website's wp-admin panel. Then I tried to log in from another user name and it got successfully logged me in, then I saw the name of my admin user has been changed. I am amazed how it was happened? who did it? and why ?

1. Please suggest me what should i do ?
2. How to avoid such incident again ?
3. Incase the culprit who did it, In the next attempt, if he/she changes name of my second user of wordpress, what i should do ?

I am afraid if the culprit change the names of my all wp users then what should i do?

Comment: use security plugins like wordpressfence, wp security. and use strong passwords and dont leak any of your usernames and passwords with anyone

Comment: First change you WP-ADMIN password immediately second change you database username and password as soon as possible.

Comment: WordPress not provide the edit user name permission once user as been created so i think changes made by directly to the database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a hacking attack.

So I suggest you first , upgrade your plugins and themes.

Then don't forget to scan your whole site with wordfence.

Then secure it with wordfence , I suggest to use it's pro version, I really feel it useful.

Then tell your hosting to scan and make sure no security issue there.

Note : Don't forget to remove your ftp and extra admin or change their password at least.

Your task is done ..

Still confusion, consult with an expert like me.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Block or delete** the mentioned admin account
2. Install a security plugin like [Wordfence](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)
3. Scan your whole site (with the plugin), it's very likely a backdoor has been installed for future attacs
4. Change all passwords of admin-accounts and advice your users to do the same
5. Change the passwords of your FTP, database and possible webserver-interface (if the username was changed, it's likely done **directly** inside the database)